# Binary Semaphore using GCD

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, synchronization, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to create a binary semaphore using GCD. I have 2 methods -> One for requesting a resource and another for releasing the resource.

Everything works fine, till the time I call request, release in order.

```
Call 1 -> Request // I get resource. Semaphore value changes to 0
Call 2 -> Release // resource is released. Semaphore value changes to 1
Call 3 -> Request // I get resource. Semaphore value changes to 0
Call 4 -> Request // Resource is denied, which is expected.
```

Problem comes up when I call release twice. I see that semaphore count increases to 2, even though it is a binary semaphore.

```
Call 1 -> Request // I get resource. Semaphore value changes to 0
Call 2 -> Release // resource is released. Semaphore value changes to 1
Call 3 -> Release // Semaphore value changes to 2
Call 4 -> Request // I get resource. Semaphore value changes to 1
Call 5 -> Request // resource is allocated twice, which is not expected. Semaphore value changes to 0
```

This is the code that I use.

```
#define WAIT_INTERVAL 2

@implementation GCDSemaphore
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t resourceAccess;
    dispatch_time_t milestone;
}

+ (GCDSemaphore *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static GCDSemaphore *instance = nil;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[GCDSemaphore alloc] init];

    });
    return instance;
}

-(id)init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        resourceAccess = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(resourceAccess);
        milestone = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(WAIT_INTERVAL * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL) requestResource
{
    long ret = dispatch_semaphore_wait(resourceAccess, milestone);
    if(ret == 0)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL) releaseResource
{
    long ret = dispatch_semaphore_signal(resourceAccess);
    return YES;
}
```

Any idea why semaphore value goes above 1? And what is the solution here? Should I check the value before calling release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispatch semaphore is not binary semaphore. It's counting semaphore.

[dispatch_semaphore_create](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_semaphore_create.3.html)

> synchronized counting semaphore

And Dispatch semaphore doesn't have any functionality to limit the maximum count. Thus the behavior is the same as expected behavior.

```
Call 1 -> Request // I get resource. Semaphore value changes to 0
Call 2 -> Release // resource is released. Semaphore value changes to 1
Call 3 -> Release // Semaphore value changes to 2
```

Pthread mutex is almost what you want. It works well with GCD but it doesn't have timeout. You need to implement timeout yourself like [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2007/Apr/msg00331.html).

- [pthread_mutex_trylock](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/pthread_mutex_trylock.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/pthread_mutex_trylock)
- [pthread_mutex_unlock](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/pthread_mutex_unlock.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/pthread_mutex_unlock)

Comment: If I want to use GCD, the I will have to implement a check for count rt?

Comment: How? You can't get the count value of Dispatch Semaphore.

Comment: I can't get the value of semaphore. But I can keep the count in my code. Basically by wrapping initialisation, requesting, and releasing methods in another class and maintaining the count in the wrapper class. I will have to lock the request and release methods. Do you see any problems with this approach?

Comment: It's doable. But why don't you use Serial Dispatch Queue? I recommend you ask a new question about what you really want to do.